How to get NT4SP5 compatibility mode working in Windows 11?
I've an application which requires NT4SP5 compatibility mode to run. On Windows 11, it will start up alright and stays up for a few seconds until it crashes with an event 1000 error.
This app behavior was exactly similar when it was tried on Windows 10. The problem was fixed by updating the registry on Windows 10:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers 

However the same trick won't work on Windows 11 (24H2). The compatibility troubleshooter didn't help.
Does anyone have any idea to get NT4SP5 compatibility mode working?

Run Windows NT 4 SP5 in a VM. That should work on almost any OS, whether Windows or Linux.
